# why is an option set inside a Jquery plugin "Null or no object" in IE8?

Tags: javascript, jquery, internet-explorer, jquery-mobile, internet-explorer-8

I have this:

```
(function ($, window) {

$.widget("mobile.multiview", $.mobile.widget, {

    options: {

        $lowerThresh: 320,
        $upperThresh: 768
    },
    framer: function () {

        var self = $(this);
        if ($.mobile.media("screen and (max-width:320px)") || ($.mobile.browser.ie && $(window).width() < self.options.$lowerThresh)) {
            var framed = "small";
        } else if ($.mobile.media("screen and (min-width:768px)") || ($.mobile.browser.ie && $(window).width() >= self.options.$upperThresh)) {
            var framed = "large";
        } else {
            var framed = "medium";
        }

        console.log(framed);

    }
})(jQuery, this);
```

This works fine in all browser, only on IE8 it returns *self.options.$lowerThresh is null or not an object*.

Any idea, why this could be? I'm using Jquery 1.7.1 and Jquery Mobile 1.1.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Why do you want to use option names starting with `$`?

Comment: At first glance only that looks uncommon/strange to me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Got it.

```
self = $(this);
```

should be:

```
self = $this;
```

Then IE plays along.

Comment: That doesn't look right. `$(this)` and `$this` have two completely different meanings. The first one takes the contextual `this` and creates a jQuery object out of it but the second one represents a JavaScript variable named `$this`. Makes no sense.